# Finding Primes, where did I got wrong?

Tags: c, primes

So...it works for small numbers but if temp is bigger than 1000, it just print 0 or random number...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int primes[10001];
    primes[10000] = 0;
    int i,temp;
    int n = 2;
    temp = 0;
    while(temp<=1000){
        for(i=2; i<n; i++){
            if(n%i == 0){
                goto Exit;
            }
        }primes[temp] = n; temp ++;
        Exit:
        n ++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<10001; i++){
        printf("%d\n",primes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `while(temp<=1000){` --> `while(temp<=10000){`

Comment: You can speed up your algorithm by 378x by only looping `i` to `sqrt(n)`. To calculate a rolling sqrt value: initialize `nr = 0`. Also, add 2 as prime at top. Then between `while(temp...)` and your `for` loop insert: `while ((nr * nr) < n) nr += 1;`. Then change the for loop to `for (i = 3; i <= nr; ++i)` For the first 30003 primes, this reduces the run time from 68.95 secs to 0.18 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The 1,000th prime is 7919](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt). [The 10,000th prime is 104,729](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt).
On some systems, an int is 16 bits (65,535). This is big enough for 1,000 primes, but not for 10,000 primes. Try changing all your int variables to long variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is temp<=1000. So your loop doesnt work when temp > 1000. I think you are supposed to give 10000 instead of 1000 in the loop condition.